# How to conclude converges of an integral if I know that $\lim _{x\to \infty }e^{2x}f\left(x\right)=3$ and $f$ continuous and bounded in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f(x)$ be continuous and bounded at $\mathbb{R}$.

And $\lim _{x\to \infty }e^{2x}f\left(x\right)=3$

prove that $\int _0^\infty\:f\left(\ln x\right)dx$ converge.

What I know is:

1)there's a function $F(x) = \int _0^xf\left(t\right)dt $

2)Since $f(x)$ continuous and bounded at $\mathbb{R}$. We can conclude that $F(x)$ is uniformly continuous at $[0,\infty)$.So for any given $ε>0$ there's a real number $M>0$ such that for any two real numbers $s,r\in[M,x):x>M$

$|\int _r^sf\left(t\right)dt| < ε$ and this implies that $\int_0^\infty\:f(x)dx$ converges

3)$f(x)$ is bounded so there's a real number $M>0$ such that for evey $x\in[0,\infty)$ ,$\;\;$$|f(x)|\le\:M$

4)$(\lim _{x\to \infty }e^{2x}f\left(x\right)=3)$ $=>$ $\frac{\left(3-ε\right)}{e^{2x}}<f\left(x\right)<\frac{\left(3+ε\right)}{e^{2x}}$ And by the sandwich theorem $\lim _{x\to \infty }f\left(x\right)=0$

Now I need to put this things together.

Comment: Is this correct ?
$\int _0^\infty\:f\left(\ln x\right)dx$  = $\int _0^\infty\:f\left(e^t\:f(t)\right)dt$
because we substitude $t=lnx$
then we know that the limit that in the question is 3 so $\left|e^{2t}f\left(t\right)-3\right|<\epsilon $ ; so  $\lim \:_{x\to \:\infty \:}e^{\frac{3}{2}t}f\left(t\right)\:=0$ which implies $\lim \:\:_{x\to \:\:\infty \:\:}e^{\frac{3}{2}t}\left|f\left(t\right)\right|=0$ from here $\:e^t\left|f\left(t\right)\right|\le \:\frac{M}{e^{\frac{1}{2}t}}$ and I know that $\:\int \:^{\infty \:}_0\:\frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{2}t}}dt$ converges and that's it.